# Pagination in a .NET Core API Project

Tags: c#, rest, pagination, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement pagination on `.NET Core` `RESTful` API's (with `EF`).

Rather than re-inventing the wheel, I was hoping there was a way to either use a generic function that could hook into the API handler and intercept requests to apply them to `EF` Query results or something built into `.NET Core` that I am un-aware of. Can anyone point me in the general direction of a library that they are aware of that does this in `.NET Core`

The way I would previously do this (and have done in non .NET Core apps) is to make a function that I have to physically add the parameters to the controller function (pageSize, pageNumber) which does get tedious (and I think a tad untidy) to add these two parameters to every single function.

Comment: EF has two usefull methods fot that: `Skip(int)` and `Take(int)`. You can combine both to get only the page you need.

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing built-in. But the way I always did it was via a class which is returned from repositories (when using repository pattern for simple applications), which implements one or two interfaces (for sorting, pagination). This way DbContext/IQueryable interface doesn't have to leak into the domain or application layer. With CQRS it's wholly different, as you would have command/queries for a specific handler

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no built-in feature for pagination, and if there was, you would not like it. Imagine a controller method returning 1.000.000 results for pagination just to pick 10 from them. It is up to you to implement the pagination.

The tedious and untidy controller methods like

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll( 
        string Filter, 
        string Whatever, 
        ..., 
        int pageNumber = 1, 
        int pageSize = 20 ) 
    { ... }
}
```

can be reorganized to

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll( GetAllArgs args ) 
    {
        IQueryable<Foo> query = ...

        return query.Paginate( args ).ToList();  
    }

    public class GetAllArgs : QueryArgsBase
    {
        public string Filter { get; set; }
        public string Whatever { get; set; }
    }
}

public interface IPaginationInfo
{ 
    int PageNumber { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
}

public abstract class QueryArgsBase : IPaginationInfo
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 20;
}

public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Paginate<T>( 
        this IQueryable<T> source, 
        IPaginationInfo pagination )
    {
        return source
            .Skip( ( pagination.PageNumber - 1 ) * pagination.PageSize )
            .Take( pagination.PageSize );
    }
}
```

Change any other controller method to have such an argument class and inherite from `QueryArgsBase` or implement `IPaginationInfo` to use the `QueryableExtensions.Paginate` method.

Comment: where should I put pagination logic if I use service layer that I call from my controllers?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a ready-to-use code based on [Sir Rufo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737694/1076848):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ProjectName.Utilities
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static async Task<PaginatedResult<T>> paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
                                                int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
            return await new PaginatedResult<T>(pageNumber, pageSize).paginate(source);
        }
    }

    public class PaginatedResult<T> : ActionResult
    {
        private const int defaultPageSize = 20;
        private const int maxPageSize = 50;

        public int total { get; private set; }
        public int limit { get; private set; }
        public int page { get; private set; }
        public List<T> objects { get; private set; }

        internal PaginatedResult(int pageNumber, int pageSize = defaultPageSize)
        {
            limit = pageSize;
            page = pageNumber;

            if (limit < 0 || limit > maxPageSize)
            {
                limit = defaultPageSize;
            }
            if (pageNumber < 0)
            {
                page = 0;
            }
        }

        internal async Task<PaginatedResult<T>> paginate(IQueryable<T> queryable)
        {
            total = queryable.Count();

            if (limit > total)
            {
                limit = total;
                page = 0;
            }

            int skip = page * limit;
            if (skip + limit > total)
            {
                skip = total - limit;
                page = total / limit - 1;
            }

            objects = await queryable.Skip(skip).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your controller:

```
// ...
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<PaginatedResult<MyDataType>>> getMyData(int pageSize = 20,
                                                                       int pageNumber = 0)
{
    return await _context.myData.AsNoTracking().paginate(pageSize, pageNumber);
}
// ...
```