# About building a pagedlist with Linq

Tags: c#

There are many examples of the paged lists in the forum, but I couldn't adapt any of them to my own model, what should I do about it, where did I go wrong? I tried a lot, where is the problem?

```
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@using DDD.Models
@model IPagedList<Model_Table>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>mmm</h2>

<div id="table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Şirket Adı</th>
                <th>Müşteri Adı</th>
                <th>Şehir</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var Item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Item.DelilListesi.Select(x=>x.Malzeme_Modeli).FirstOrDefault()</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, _sayfaNo => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { SayfaNo = _sayfaNo }))
</div>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DDD.Models;
using PagedList;

namespace DDDD.Controllers
{
    public class DenemeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Deneme
        DDDEntities _db = new DDDEntities();
        public ActionResult Index(int? pagesize)
        {
            int _pagesize = pagesize ?? 1;
            var dddd = from o in _db.table1
                              join a in _db.table2 on o.table1_ID
                              equals a.Table2_ID
                              join c in _db.table3 on a.Table2_ID
                              equals c.table3_ID.ToString()
                              select new D1List
                              {
                                  A1 = o.B1,
                                  A2 = o.B2,
                                  A3 = a.B3,
                              };
            Model_Table model = new Model_Table();
            model.D1Lists = dddd.ToList();
            model.D1Lists.OrderByDescending(m => m.table_name).ToPagedList<D1List>(_pagesize, 10);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement pagination in asp.net core razor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928891/how-to-implement-pagination-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages)

Comment: or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736000/pagination-in-a-net-core-api-project/43737694#43737694

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have a problem but there really isn't enough details about what your actual problem is or what unexpected behaviour you are experiencing?

The `DenemeController` `Index` method retrieves the data from the database using LINQ-to-SQL queries, and creates a `Model_Table` object to pass to the view. The `pagesize` parameter is used to specify the number of items per page in the paged list.

I assume that your `Model_Table` class has something like so to hold the `pagedList`

```
public class Model_Table
{
    public IPagedList<D1List> D1Lists { get; set; }
}
```

When i have used the `PagedList` library in the past I have bound my view to my own custom model so using your example, for the model declaration I would change `@model IPagedList<Model_Table>` to `@model Model_Table`

Then in the view, since the `PagedListPager` helper method requires a `PagedList.IPagedList` object as its first argument i would change yours from

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, _sayfaNo => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { SayfaNo = _sayfaNo }))
```

to

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.D1Lists, _sayfaNo => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { pagesize = _sayfaNo }))
```

(Basically I am passing in the `IPagedList<D1List>` `D1Lists` that is defined on your `Model_Table` class)

Just looking at the ordering code in your controller and it looks like you are not assigning the result of the `OrderByDescending` method to any variable, so the ordering operation has no effect on the List. might be better to do

```
model.D1Lists = dddd.OrderByDescending(m => m.table_name).ToPagedList<D1List>(_pagesize, 10);
```

Good luck with it.